# Can't get Bootstrap ScrollSpy to work on my page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I read dozens of examples and tutorials but on my page I can't get Bootstrap ScrollSpy to work. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="nav_bar">
    <div class="container">

        <nav id="nav_anchors">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#top">Aktion</a></li>
                <li><a href="#content_produkte">Produkte</a></li>
                <li><a href="#content_tarif">Tarif</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- ... some other elements ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#nav_anchors' });
```

Here is my page in development:

http://www.handyservice.de/de/top-angebote/test-landingpage-4/angebot.html

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please try to abstract your problem down into small sections of reproducible code instead of providing a link to your own web page with tons of code. **See also**: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1366033).

Comment: Thank your for the advice. Actually I tried with the code above but was sure I was missing something so I pasted also the link to the my development page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

According to the [docs on scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#callout-scrollspy-target-ids):

> **Resolvable ID targets required**
>   Navbar links must have resolvable id targets. For example, a `<a href="#home">home</a>` must correspond to something in the DOM like `<div id="home"></div>`.

Meaning the anchor href must contain and only contain the location hash of the target section.

#### Fix 1 - Only include anchors

*Works*:   `<a href="#content_tarif">Tarif</a>`
*Doesn't*: `<a href="/angebot.html#content_tarif">Tarif</a>`

**Here's a working example in Stack Snippets**:

```js
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#nav_anchors' });
```

```css
#nav_bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

li.active {
  background: #CFCFFF;
}

body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

section {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div id="nav_bar">
  <div class="container">

    <nav id="nav_anchors">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#top">Aktion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#content_produkte">Produkte</a></li>
        <li><a href="#content_tarif">Tarif</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</div>

<section id="top">top</section>
<section id="content_produkte">content_produkte</section>
<section id="content_tarif">content_tarif</section>
```

#### Fix 2 - Add Data-Target Attribute

If for some reason you can't change the href attribute of your links, you can optionally provide the `data-target` attribute for each anchor tag to explicitly declare the target

You'll notice that the scrollspy selector will accept either.  Here's the [relevant source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/scrollspy.js#L109):

```js
var selector = this.selector + '[data-target="' + target + '"],' +
               this.selector + '[href="' + target + '"]'
```

Which turns into something like this:

```js
var selector = '#nav_anchors .nav li > a[data-target="#content_tarif"],' + 
               '#nav_anchors .nav li > a[href="#content_tarif"]'
```

So scrollspy will work fine if you update your links like this:

```
<a href="de/#content_tarif" data-target="#content_tarif">Tarif</a>
```

**Here's a working example in Stack Snippets**:

```js
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#nav_anchors' });
```

```css
#nav_bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

li.active {
  background: #CFCFFF;
}

body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

section {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div id="nav_bar">
  <div class="container">

    <nav id="nav_anchors">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="de/#top" data-target="#top">Aktion</a></li>
        <li><a href="de/#content_produkte" data-target="#content_produkte">content_produkte</a></li>
        <li><a href="de/#content_tarif" data-target="#content_tarif">Tarif</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</div>

<section id="top">top</section>
<section id="content_produkte">content_produkte</section>
<section id="content_tarif">content_tarif</section>
```

Comment: Thank your so much! The content management framework ads the URI to the anchors automatically. So my template looked completely right but the HTML output was different.